# Not able to use content inheritance in Crafter CMS

Tags: crafter-cms

Following [this](https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/content-inheritance.html) documentation, I was trying to implement content inheritance but I could not.

My simple use case is:

Parent component contains CSS data.
Child component inherits from it and populates its template with CSS links.

In documentation:

**Child: Below is the XML file of a page residing under the above level descriptor and is setup to inherit from it. You’ll note the definition of the merge-strategy as inherit-levels, this invokes the level-based inheritance mechanics that require Crafter CMS to look at current and higher levels for files named crafter-level-descriptor.level.xml (this is configurable). You’ll also note that this page doesn’t specify the CSS file/group of files to include, nor will it need to specify the header nor footer components.**

In child page's `config.xml` file there is no reference of parent.

My question are?

1. Where to create `crafter-level-descriptor.level.xml` using studio?
2. `page residing under the above level descriptor` what does this mean, what kind of levels?

Note: I am new to crafter-cms and sometimes the documentation is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent and child here refer to instances of the content, not the content type definition.

Levels refer to folders in a hierarchy.

`crafter-level-descriptor.level.xml` is a file created on a folder or subfolder, and items (XML files) that have the `inherit-levels` inheritance strategy defined will inherit from the level descriptor `crafter-level-descriptor.level.xml` adjacent to the item (same folder level) and higher levels (parent folders) all the way to the root folder.

For common concerns that you'd like a section (folder hierarchy) to inherit, specify that at a parent level, and have the children (pages or components with that inheritance strategy), defined to have 'inherit-levels' strategy and those metadata fields will automatically show up in the child items, even if not defined in their model.